# Only XOR gate synthesizing Yosys

Tags: xor, synthesis, yosys

I want to synthesize a circuit with Yosys, but I want the synthesized circuit to consist only of XOR gates. how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

`synth; abc -g XOR`

(this will actually map to XOR gates and inverters, which can easily be implemented using XOR gates. If you need a netlist of only XORs them techmap can be used to convert an inverter to a XOR with constant 1).

Comment: Hi,
Thanks of Answer. but when i do what you say i get an error and yosys shuts down.
ERROR:
Mapping has failed.
can't open ABC output file '/tmp/yosys-abc-Lihxnv/output.blif'

Comment: do you get any more output? you might want to create a github issue with the full details.